# Preserve local procedures when creating a procedure file from source + local procedures

Tags: halcon

This pseudo source is the layout of my Halcon application:

```cs
[sourceCode]
[sourceCode]
[sourceCode]
[localProcedure]
[sourceCode]
[localProcedure]
[sourceCode]
```

When I create a procedure file (.hdvp) of the above pseudo source the local procedure's content is lost. Is there a way to preserve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with the procedure, but you can save and run an entire program in HDevEngine if that's what you're after.